# PinPoint on Google Maps and display the map in Activity

Tags: android, google-maps

i am using google maps v2 and i'm new to it, what i'm doing is i open the map by pressing a button, the thing is that i need to pinpoint a certain location on the map and get its longitude and latitude to display the map again in another activity with the pinpointed location.

i'm a bit confused on how to manipulate google maps and how to display it in other activity, what do i need to add to the following code bellow??

here is my map code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Location currentLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            updateLocation(currentLocation);
        } else {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Current location is NULL");
        }
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    } else {
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    Activity#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 1, locationListener);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 1, locationListener);

        Location locationGPS = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location locationNet = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Location loc;
        long GPSLocationTime = 0;
        if (null != locationGPS) {
            GPSLocationTime = locationGPS.getTime();
        }

        long NetLocationTime = 0;

        if (null != locationNet) {
            NetLocationTime = locationNet.getTime();
        }

        if (0 < GPSLocationTime - NetLocationTime) {
            loc = locationGPS;
        } else {
            loc = locationNet;
        }
        if (loc != null) {
            updateLocation(loc);
        }
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    }


}


private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        updateLocation(loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}

public void updateLocation(Location loc) {
    Toast.makeText(
            getBaseContext(),
            "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                    + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
    Log.v(getClass().getName(), longitude);
    String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
    Log.v(getClass().getName(), latitude);

    /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
    String cityName = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<Address> addresses;
    /*try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), (addresses.get(0).getLocality() == null ? "Null" : addresses.get(0).getLocality()));
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: "
            + cityName;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 13));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(cityName)
            .snippet("My Location")
            .position(myLocation));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by pinpoint you mean tap to add a point on the map then use the code :

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));

                //To Send this point to second mapsActivity
                Intent i=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity1.class);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable("POINT", point);
                i.putExtra("bundle",args);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

To create another map activity just right click on "app" folder->New->Google->Google MapsActivity.
A new Activity will be added.

Inside the new MapsActivity's onCreate() get this point by :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
LatLng markerPoint = bundle.getParcelable("POINT");
```

Inside the second mapsActivity's setUpMapIfNeeded() :

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPoint));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(markerPoint, 10));
```

Here 10 is the zoomlevel adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get LatLongs of marker by `marker.getPosition()`. just send these values via intent extras to your next activity and display it again on the map in that activity.

Comment: yes thank you .. what Akhil answered me below helped me, thank you again @Dhananjay Kulkami